# Confused how lighting works in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So after trying many things it seems nothing works. I checked the documentation on lights and it simply fails. How come I can see my object even though I have not added any lights? I suppose that could be the cause. Again im not entirely sure. I managed to set up a basic scene with a basic geometry.

I want the scene to be dark and add some spot light to the sphere.

http://jsfiddle.net/3dnx7L3m/4/

Again adding some spot light does not create any light. Maybe I need to set the ambient light before I set the spot light.

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
scene.add(light);
```

How do you darken the canvas and set up the lights as shown in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` doesnt work for you because it does not take lighting into account. Change it to `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3dnx7L3m/7/

Comment: I managed to fix this a while ago now but with textures its pretty weird http://jsfiddle.net/3dnx7L3m/8/

Comment: Read the console error, this is a CORS Problem. I fixed it here with ```loader.crossOrigin = '';```: http://jsfiddle.net/3dnx7L3m/9/.

Comment: Interesting, I googled a bit before and thought that had to do with the image being non-power of two (which was never the case), the lighting or the image not having been completed. Tried an onload as well. Funny thing is I have a chrome plugin that should have allowed all CORS.

Comment: Hey, so thank you a lot for pointing out the actual cause. How did you know it was a cross origin problem though? It never mentioned cors in the console

Comment: The console told me: ```It is forbidden to load a WebGL texture from a tainted canvas. A Canvas becomes tainted for example when a cross-domain image is drawn on it.```. Have fun exploring three.js :-)